# Asynchronous evaluation in ipython parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipython, ipython-parallel

Since the awesome `1.0.0` release I've been playing around with `iPython` parallel interface. What I'm trying to do is to set up a asynchronous stochastic gradient descent system. The way I see it, I want to send a function to all the nodes and get the results as they come out. From what I was able to implement and glance from the documentation the standard views implemented don't really support that. The `get(timeout)` method would do that, but you can't really loop through every entry in a `<ASync_result>` object using a timeout. The way I managed to get it running was the following

```
c = Client()
calls = []
for i,j in enumerate(args):
    calls.append( c[ i % len( c.ids ) ].apply( f, j ) )

while condition:
    dels = []
    for i,j in enumerate( calls ):
         try:
             print j.get(0.01) #or some other timeout
             dels.append( i ) #I keep track of the calls that have been called
             #do something with the last result, throw a new call
             calls.append( c[ i % len(c.ids) ].apply( f, argument )
         except:
             pass

    for i,d in enumerate( dels ):
         del calls[ d - i ] #delete gotten calls

    #evaluate stopping condition
```

Now, before you all go screaming that this is horrible code and a stupid way to do that, I know it. I could make this particular way of doing it nicer, but I'm just wondering if there is some built-in way of doing something similar in IPython.parallel.

Thanks in advance to anyone taking the time.

Best,
Al.

Comment: What's the point of doing it async, when you have a while loop that waits for all the tasks to finish? You just implemented a sync execution on top of the async API :)

Comment: True, but eventually I'd like to implement a loop that keeps throwing new calls and gets them as they come out. I'll update that in the example.

Comment: My aim is to implement an assynchronous sgd for a neural network. So the calls can be somewhat out-of-sync with the current parameters. And I'd keep calling them until the error changes less than a certain amount as a moving average or something of the like. And damn, Viktor, you sure are quick on the ipython tag! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple async calls, and then iterate through them.

```
c = Client()
dview = c[:]
asyncs = [dview.map_async(f, [arg]) for arg in args]
while asyncs:
    for async in asyncs[:]:
        if async.ready():
            asyncs.remove(async)
            print async.result[0]
```